# How to declare QueryFullProcessImageName() API C# (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: c#, winapi, declaration, windows-7-x64

I need to use it, but in pinvoke i can't get the declaration of that API.

So... is there a way for declare it?.

And if your got an example for use it would be perfect, because is the first time i gonna use that api.

Comment: Don't use this, WMI can get you this info as well with a lot less pain and no dependency on Vista+.  Use WMI Code Creator, it lets you experiment and generates the C# code you need.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

//...

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint dwFlags,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder lpExeName,
    ref uint lpdwSize);
```

For the usage, [see the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!. I will test it, but... however i want to know something... How do you made it?... is there a manual or something?

Comment: @Krahne: I learned C. :) I suggest you do the same, it's not that hard but when you do, you see what's happening. :)

Comment: How much time you invested to learn C? .. Do you know of any specific book?, if you know of one in Spanish, i'll really appreciate it because I do not speak much English. Thanks for everything, I'm still testing the API.

Comment: In my LINQPad the "MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)" part causes strange chinese letters in the result, removing the attribute yields correct path with latin letters. Any idea why does this error occur? LINQPad is 32-bit, running under 64-bit Win7, but it should not matter.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: Hmm I forget if you need `CharSet = CharSet.Auto`, try putting that inside `DllImport`?

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks, yes, `CharSet = CharSet.Auto` helped.